# Need help PHP query update a table with character (+ , =)

Tags: php

i have made an API HWID for my application in C#; I have some problems updating my table.

My table is called: HWID

when i send a request to my API:

`http://website/execute.phpaction=sendhwid&username=****&HWID=XTjs0vmQMRTZxa/r5xp23+0WYlxfxpZW271Eq7XJvpufCf4Ldhrz4TjTVEHJ4bf0`

it sends the HWID:

`XTjs0vmQMRTZxa/r5xp23+0WYlxfxpZW271Eq7XJvpufCf4Ldhrz4TjTVEHJ4bf0` in my table HWID.

for the moment all work but HWID have a character + so when i update with this in my database it's remove the `+` and it's changed to a space:

`XTjs0vmQMRTZxa/r5xp23 
0WYlxfxpZW271Eq7XJvpufCf4Ldhrz4TjTVEHJ4bf0`

it's actually what i see in my table, i don't know how to fix that for allow the `+` or some others character in my table.

My code PHP is:

```
 case "sendhwid":
        $r = $login->sendhwid($_GET["username"], $_GET["HWID"]);
        break;

 public function sendhwid($username, $HWID){
        if(empty($username) || empty($HWID)) return "ERROR";
         $this->query("UPDATE apipremium SET HWID = ? WHERE apipremium.username = ?", array($HWID, $username));
         return "OK";
         }
```

Comment: You need to URL encode those characters they are not safe to transport in a URL like that.  Some sort of URL_encode or equivalent to encode the special characters.  The plus sign is a shorthand for a space character within a URL that is why you get this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to encode your url parameters before sending in your function.

Try like this

```
 case "sendhwid":
        $r = $login->sendhwid($_GET["username"], urlencode($_GET["HWID"]));
        break;
```

Comment: Thanks but when i add my HWID with the character + it's make: ```XTjs0vmQMRTZxa/r5xp23 0WYlxfxpZW271Eq7XJvpufCf4Ldhrz4TjTVEHJ4bf0```

Comment: Oh finaly it's working, thanks you so much for your great help